# Differences between two common RS485 to TTL modules

Tags: rs485

I want to "translate" existing code that utilizes one of these modules for the other module.

Specifically, I have code that utilizes an "RS485 to TTL converter". As you can see in this picture:

[image]

The side that connects to the Arduino has four pins, VCC, GND, TX, and RX, but out of those pins, only two are data pins.

However, if we look at the MAX485 module:

[image]

The Arduino side has four pins as well, DI, DE, RE, and RO.
However, all four of these pins are data pins.

Since the protocol is the same, how come the pins are different?

In the "RS485 to TTL converter" code, `SoftWareSerial` is being used, and it gets the two pins that will eventually connect to the TX and RX on the module as arguments.

How can I translate this code for the MAX485? How should the pinout be?

**EDIT:** I find it funny that I won the "notable question badge (question with 2500 views)"... And then I look and it has a -1 rating. lol

Comment: Your edit has extended the question to the point where the answer I gave no longer applies.

Comment: @timemage I am very sorry. I didn't know that it would come down to this... Sorry for your wasted time... And thank you for taking the time to answer as well.

Comment: @user1584421, I did a 'rollback'. please ask a new question for the ModbusServer library problem

Comment: It's not a waste exactly, but it creates complications when the question is updated to that degree when it has an answer. I wasn't about to roll back your question myself to bring them back to consistent and I wasn't prepared to update it to address the new question and to stop addressing all of the old stuff you'd integrated into the new question.

Answer (score 4):

So far as I'm able to tell, your first module must have a feature that automatically enabled RS485 driver when you are sending and disabled it as soon as you aren't. This is not an uncommon feature.

The latter doesn't support it apparently. It looks like a common MAX485 type design which doesn't. Instead it exposes driver enable and receiver enable pins. These are normally active at opposite levels, which allows you to tie them together and run them to a single pin on the Arduino for controlling both at the same time. Any code that you had using the prior module would need to be changed to manually enable the driver when sending and then disable it afterwards.

You would need an extra digital pin (`PIN_DE_RE`) connected from the Arduino to the module, to both of its RE and DE pins. It would need to be set to output in `setup()` with `pinMode(PIN_DE_RE, OUTPUT);` And set to low `digitalWrite(PIN_DE_RE, LOW);` for a chip following the MAX485 design such that the receiver is enabled and driver disabled initially.

Your write transactions would then need to look like this:

```cpp
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(PIN_DE_RE, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
your_serial.write(whatever); // or .print etc
your_serial.flush();
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(PIN_DE_RE, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(10);
```

You *may* not need explicit delays around the `digitalWrite` since `digitalWrite` is often slow enough anyway, but the point of them is to give support the minimum time needed between changing the RE/DE pins and a transaction. I picked 10uS somewhat arbitrarily.  More than anything it's just there to raise the point that the timing between the signal change and sending/receiving is important.

For `SoftwareSerial` `.flush()` does nothing usually, at least it doesn't on the AVR. But I include it just to make the point that whatever you use to send serial you must make sure the transaction has left the actual device and not merely been queued for send before disabling the RS485 driver. If you were doing this with `Serial1` on a Leonardo/Micro/Mega etc it would be important. I'd leave `.flush()` as is for `SoftwareSerial` in part because it won't cost you anything to do so and it will make things work if you switch to a buffered-output type serial connection.

Comment: Thank you very much! With your help, i understood how the module works. However, I get a 226 error, which means timeout. I have the question updated with the code. If you happen to know what is going on.... You can omit the relatively large `if` statement, since it is not being executed. The code is quite small.

Answer (score 2):

RS485 is a standard for a communication bus with potentially multiple senders, of course not at the same time. As such, a device needs to disable its transmitting circuit to let others communicate. The application layer protocol is not defined by RS485.

For this reason, a good driver module provides two control inputs beside the data lines:

- DE is "driver enable". It needs to be active, if the device wants to drive the bus and send its message.
- RE is "receiver enable". It needs to be active, if the device wants to listen to the bus and receive some message.

The data lines are commonly denoted like this:

- DI is "driver input". If you use the ubiquitous serial communication, this is the same as TXD.
- RO is "receiver output". If you use the ubiquitous serial communication, this is the same as RXD.

---

How does this work in the module that only has TXD and RXD?

Well, the hardware assumes some specific baud rate, which should be documented.

As soon as the start bit is detected on TXD, the module internally activates the driver (DE). It might additionally disable the receiver (RE) to avoid reception of the message as an echo.

This activation is controlled by a timer that lasts at least as long as the transmission at the specific baud rate needs to be sent.

---

Now, what to do with the MAX485 module's control lines?

You can connect TXD to DI and RXD to RO, respectively.

If your module simply uses the driver chip manufactured by Maxim, the control input RE has actually inverted logic. This means, the receiver is active, if the line is low. In contrast, the driver is active, if the line DE is high.

Put appropriate calls of `digitalWrite()` at the places where you want to send something to the sensor. Please be aware that the transmission needs some time. You need to make sure that all bits are sent before you disable the driver.

If you only want to receive from the sensor, just disable the driver and enable the receiver all the time.

Comment: this was all in a now deleted answer by timemage. OP needs a solution with the ModbusMaster library

Comment: Thank you but as Juraj said, i know this information at the time you wrote the answer. This has already been implemented, i am now getting a timeout error.

Comment: @Juraj I never saw timemage's answer. And from the comment I cannot conclude what was its contents. -- The question does not mention an issue with the library, but with the connections.

Comment: @user1584421 PLEASE edit your question if the issue you describe in the prose is cleared. Or better delete the question, and post a new one with the actual question.

Comment: In the bottom of the question, it has all the connections listed... Perhaps i should change the title of the question?

Comment: I did a 'rollback' of the question and undeleted timemage's answer

Comment: @user1584421 This is not a forum. If your question is answered in one way or the other, mark the best answer, or comment asking for clarification, for example. If you have a new issue, post a new question. You might want to take the [tour].

Comment: @Juraj Thank you very much! Now it is much better.

Comment: just a small note. user1584421 is a member for 8 years and has more than 1300 rep points from more than 50 questions and 6 answers